# nodejs, multer, aws S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, uuid, multer-s3

How do i apply uuid and date so that the filename stored in my database and the filename stored in my S3 bucket are the same?

With this current implementation, the uuid and the date are always the same even if a post was made hours later.

Can someone help, would really appreciate it.

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
 accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ID,
 secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET,
 region:process.env.AWS_REGION
 })

const uid =uuidv4();
const date =new Date().toISOString()

const multerS3Config = multerS3({
      s3: s3,
      bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
      metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
               cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname }); },
      shouldTransform: true,
      acl: 'public-read',
      contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
      transforms: [
                  {
                    id: 'full',
                    key: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, file.originalname 
                         + "-"  + `${date}` + "-" + `${uid}` + 
                         "_full.jpg"),
                    transform: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, 
                               sharp().resize(2000).jpeg({ 
                               quality: 50 }))
                   },
                   {
                     id: 'thumb',
                     key: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, 
                          file.originalname + "-"  + 
                          `${date}` + "-" + `${uid}` + "_thumb.jpg"),
                     transform: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, 
                                sharp().resize(100).jpeg({ 
                                quality: 30 }))
                   },
                   ],
                });

const upload = multer({
storage: multerS3Config,
limits: { fieldSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024 },
});
```

Here is my post request

```
router.post(
"/",
 [    upload.array("images", config.get("maxImageCount"))],
 async (req, res) => {
const paths = await req.files.map((file) => ({ originalName: file.originalname + "-" + 
`${date}` 
+ "-" + `${uid}`}));
await Post.create({
title: req.body.title,
userId: req.body.userId,
Post_Images: paths.map((x) => ({ images: x.originalName })),
},
{ 
include: [Post_Image] }).then(
res.status(201).send())
```

With this current implementation the the files are getting stored in both the db and s3.

Also, another question i have is what is the difference between using multer and multer-s3? I tried using multer to post the images to s3 but it did not work so i used multer-s3 and it worked.

***UPDATE***

```
 const s3 = new AWS.S3({
 accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ID,
 secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET,
 region:process.env.AWS_REGION
 })

function getFilename() {
return new Date().toISOString() + '-' + uuidv4();
}

function getTransforms() {
const fileName = getFilename();
return {
transforms:[
  {
      id: 'full',
      key: (req, file, cb) => {
        let fname = file.originalname.split(".");
        cb(null, fname[0] + '-' + fileName + "_full.jpg")},
      transform: (req, file, cb) => cb(null,
          sharp().resize(2000).jpeg({
              quality: 50
          }))
  },
  {
      id: 'thumb',
      key: (req, file, cb) => {
        let fname = file.originalname.split(".");
        cb(null, fname[0] + '-' + fileName + "_thumb.jpg")},
      transform: (req, file, cb) => cb(null,
          sharp().resize(100).jpeg({
              quality: 30
          }))
  }
  ],
metadata: (req, file, cb) => {
let fname = file.originalname.split(".");
cb(null, { 
    fieldName: file.fieldname, 
    key: fname[0] + '-' + fileName
});
}}}

const multerS3Config = multerS3({
      s3: s3,
      bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
      shouldTransform: true,
      acl: 'public-read',
      contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
      ...getTransforms()
      });

const upload = multer({
storage: multerS3Config,
limits: { fieldSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024 },
});
```

Here is my post request

```
router.post(
"/",
 [    upload.array("images", config.get("maxImageCount"))],
 async (req, res) => {

const paths = await req.files.map((file) => ({ images: 
              file.transforms[0].metadata.key}));

await Post.create({
title: req.body.title,
userId: req.body.userId,
Post_Images: paths,
},
{ 
include: [Post_Image] }).then(
res.status(201).send())
```

My problem is `the date and uuid variables both will initialize when node server start, it never changes until your node server restarts`

Comment: I will try to get through this.

Comment: @Arya really appreciate it, i simply want my filename in db and in s3 to be unique and the same so i can render the images from s3

Comment: @Arya did you manage to get through this?

Comment: i have tried a lot but unable to do that

Comment: is there any break through for this error "SignatureDoesNotMatch: null"

Comment: Thank you for the effort appreciate it :) I dont get an error my problem is that the filename in my database is different than in my AWS S3, so in my frontend the file does not get rendered

Comment: i was stuck with above error

Comment: in postman are you using body-form data ?

Comment: i was just shifted to digital ocean and following this https://glitch.com/edit/#!/spaces-node-app?path=server.js%3A29%3A24

Comment: will have a look at this link now and update you

Comment: this is link to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65490170/getting-signaturedoesnotmatch-null-error-while-uploading-imagse-to-digitalocean

Comment: To the second question: `multer` is a middleware for parsing files from incoming POST requests. `multer-s3` is multer + automatic uploads to S3, `multer-s3-transform` is multer + S3 + batch transformations ;-)

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' thank you for the clarification i really needed it, appreciate it. I also updated my code if you can have a look.

Comment: Would it not make more sense to store the AWS URL in the database instead ?

Comment: @Pogrindis i am storing the filename since in my get request i am adding the url and extension to the filename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick fixes:

- remain same

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET,
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION
});
```

- the `date` and `uuid` variables both will initialize when node server start, it will never change until your node server restart, you just need to put it in to a function to return every time new file name,
- here function returns filename except extension

```
function getFilename() {
    return new Date().toISOString() + '-' + uuidv4();
}
```

- create function for transforms and pass same filename in both version from `getFilename()` function, add filename in metadata as well,

```
function getTransforms() {
    const fileName = getFilename();
    return {
        transforms: [
            {
                id: "full",
                key: (req, file, cb) => {
                    let fname = file.originalname.split(".")
                    cb(null, fname[0] + '-' + fileName + "_full.jpg")
                },
                transform: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, sharp().resize(2000).jpeg({ quality: 50 }))
            },
            {
                id: "thumb",
                key: (req, file, cb) => {
                    let fname = file.originalname.split(".")
                    cb(null, fname[0] + '-' + fileName + "_thumb.jpg")
                },
                transform: (req, file, cb) => cb(null, sharp().resize(100).jpeg({ quality: 30 }))
            }
        ],
        metadata: (req, file, cb) => {
            let fname = file.originalname.split(".");
            cb(null, { 
                fieldName: file.fieldname, 
                key: fname[0] + '-' + fileName + ".jpg"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

- call `getTransforms()` function, that will return transforms and matadata properties
- i am not sure aboutyour login to store filename in database,
- get name from `transfoems.metadata` that we passed from metadata, this will return only _full name,

```
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {

    const multerS3Config = multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET,
        shouldTransform: true,
        acl: 'public-read',
        contentType: multerS3.AUTO_CONTENT_TYPE,
        ...getTransforms()
    });

    const upload = multer({
        storage: multerS3Config,
        limits: { fieldSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024 }
    });

    upload.array("images", config.get("maxImageCount"))(req, res, async(error) => {
        const paths = await req.files.map((file) => ({
            images: file.transforms[0].metadata.key
        }));
        await Post.create({
            title: req.body.title,
            userId: req.body.userId,
            Post_Images: paths,
        }, {
            include: [Post_Image]
        })
    });
    
})
```

---

Basically the statement **multer-s3 Streaming multer storage engine for AWS S3.** is enough to differentiate both multer and multer-s3.

> The code has not been tested, you can workaround and see what's happen!

Comment: kd, once its been encoded it will have a uid, to log it you need to recursively stringify the object. have you tested it / debugged it ?

Comment: @Pogrindis yes, but it is not working. I just want the uuid and date to be the same for each file uploaded to database and s3.

Comment: @turivishal IT WORKED :) your a legend, thank you so much, i really appreciate your help alot. Hope you have an amazing day