# Getting SignatureDoesNotMatch: null error while uploading images to DigitalOcean Spaces using multers3 node.js

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, multer, spaces, multer-s3

```
Error: code:'SignatureDoesNotMatch'
extendedRequestId:undefined
message:null
name:'SignatureDoesNotMatch'
region:null
```

```
// Load dependencies
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const multerS3 = require('multer-s3');

const app = express();

// Set S3 endpoint to DigitalOcean Spaces
const spacesEndpoint = new aws.Endpoint('fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com');
const s3 = new aws.S3({
    endpoint: spacesEndpoint,
    accessKeyId: '*************',
    secretAccessKey: '**********************************'
});

// Change bucket property to your Space name
const upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: 'bucket',
        acl: 'public-read',
        key: function (request, file, cb) {
            console.log(file);
            cb(null, file.originalname);
        }
    })
}).array('upload', 1);

// Views in public directory
app.use(express.static('public'));

// Main, error and success views
app.get('/', function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

app.get("/success", function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/success.html');
});

app.get("/error", function (request, response) {
    response.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/error.html');
});

app.post('/upload', function (request, response, next) {
    upload(request, response, function (error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return response.redirect("/error");
        }
        console.log('File uploaded successfully.');
        response.redirect("/success");
    });
});

app.listen(3001, function () {
    console.log('Server listening on port 3001.');
});
```

Trying this [blog](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upload-a-file-to-object-storage-with-node-js) for digital ocean spaces example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem, the only thing that helped was to reset the keys

Comment: This worked for me too

Comment: Only thing that works, would totally recommend starting from here before going down a rabbit hole and trying everything else, especially if it breaks suddenly. In my case, it was working in all cloud environments and locally for my team. It just broke on my local machine and out of the blue. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm Livius answer. I had the same issue. Without any changes to the code, I created new access keys and it started working. For your reference, here my setup code snipped:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------
....
var aws = require('aws-sdk');

// --------- AWS SETUP -------------

aws.config.update({
  accessKeyId: '..........',
  secretAccessKey: '.......',
  region: "eu-central-1",
  signatureVersion: 'v4',
  signatureCache: false
});

let s3 = new aws.S3();

.. and so on...

// --------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

4 hours of trying... I have accidentaly exchanged meaning of "bucket" and "key". Bucket is the simple name of the storage section WITHOUT folder structure, KEY is the filename INCLUDING folder structure.

This error means "Bucket not found".